# Is there better way of iteration to find the evenly divisible number?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I'm trying to solve this problem: 
"2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.

What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?"

Please, do not tell me the answer, I really want to solve it by myself. All I need is an advice regarding math aspect of the question. The thing is adding one every cycle isn't a good idea because the process is too slow. Or is there a problem with variable type not being long?

I've tried to get number which is evenly divisible of all numbers between (1 and 10), and even (1 and 17), and the algorithm worked well.

```
int in_num = 1;
int score = 0;
public void calculate() {
    while (true) {
        score = 0;
        for (int x = 1; x < 21; x++) {
            if ((in_num%x) == 0) {
                score++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number " + in_num + " has " + score );
        if (score == 20) {
            System.out.println(in_num);
            break;
        }
        in_num++;
    }
```

I expect the specific integer, but I get infinite loop.

Comment: "Or is there a problem with variable type not being long?" - Is the answer a number that is representable as an `int`?   Hint: you could test for that ... when you increment `in_num`

Comment: Also, can I recommend that you use a spelling checker.  The first version had THREE spelling errors in the title.  And the indentation of the code was messed up.

Comment: The thing is I don't have answer yet, because the loop is not gonna stop. But the number 232775004, which is the example of numbers of the loop, seems available for int type in java.

Comment: What makes you think that?  Have you checked what the largest allowed value for `int` is?

Comment: Your code breaks only when score is 20; that does not happen

Comment: You could calculate the upper limit of the answer, right? That allows you to check @StephenC’s suggestion.

Comment: Hint: if you add 1 to a positive number, and it overflows, the result will be negative.  Hint 2: `Integer.MAX_VALUE` ... read about it in the javadoc.

Comment: The smallest divisible number of all numbers from 1 to 20 will be the LCM of all numbers from 1 to 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lowest common multiple of two numbers *x* and *y* is *xy/GCD(x,y)*, where *GCD* calculates the greatest common divisor.

You can implement GCD easily using Euclid's algorithm or the binary GCD algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor

The algorithm would be like:

```
result = 1;
for (x = 20; x > 0; --x)
    result *= (x/GCD(x,result));
```

Of course this works for other numbers as well.  If you really don't care about that, then you can just print 232792560

Answer (score 4):

Isn't this enough?

Multiply every prime number from 1 to 20 to get the number! Also instead of 2 use 16 and instead of 3 use 9.

```java
Long number = 2 ^ 4 * 3 ^ 2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19L;
System.out.println(number);
```

***Detailed Answer:***

We need to find every prime number less than 20. After that, for each prime number, we must calculate the number to which we can exponentiate the prime number while it stays less than 20.

For example, if we multiply 2 four times with itself it remains below 20 (16). But if we calculate 2 to the fifth, it will be 32 which is greater than 20.

We will do the same for every other prime number. By this calculation the actual answer will be like this:

```java
Long number = 2 ^ 4 * 3 ^ 2 * 5 ^ 1 * 7 ^ 1 * 11 ^ 1 * 13 ^ 1 * 17 ^ 1 * 19L ^ 1;
```

Comment: Would you kindly explain why should we multiply 2 ^ 4 and 3 ^ 2 instead of 2 and 3. Thank you.

Comment: I updated the answer. Although, the scientific answer is the @matt-timmermans one. This one is a simple-to-understand answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an infinite loop because of int (in_num) range exceeded its length; replace type int to Long (something bigger than int) you will not get any infinite loop and you will get your output.

Comment: Thanks, I just thought that int, which bound is 2 147 483 647, would be sufficient.